# Bash always evaluate Regex as true

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

In a script, there's these lines

```
#!/bin/bash

...

if ! [[ $SCREEN_NAME =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$ ]]; then
  echo "The Server title contains invalid symbole. Only a-z A-Z 0-9 - _ . are allowed"
  exit 1;
fi
```

The problem is that, whatever value `$SCREEN_NAME` is set to, the script always exit with that message. I have tried reading regular expressions with Bash, and I see nothing wrong with it. What am I missing?

### Update

Following comments and answers, I echoed `$SCREEN_NAME`, and nothing seemed wrong... until I did

```
echo "*$SCREEN_NAME*"
```

and saw that the second asterisk was put on a new line. Here's how `$SCREEN_NAME` is set :

```
SCREEN_NAME=$(grep -i 'server_screen_title' server.properties  | cut -f2 -d'=')
```

The value is read from the INI like config file. The interesting line is

```
server_screen_title=Test-Server
```

And I believe the value holds the terminating character `\n`. Thus the test fails. I've read man for `cut`, but I'm not sure how to fix this, nor if I'm right on this one.

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x`.

Comment: Seems to work fine, the problem must be within the "$SCREEN_NAME".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was too quick on this one, your test works. I suspect you somehow have set `$SCREEN_NAME` either globally or previously in the script as a string containing an illegal character.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$` matches a non-NULL string containing only the allowed characters, so if `$SCREEN_NAME` is a non-NULL string containing only the allowed characters, `$SCREEN_NAME =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$`'s value is 0.

`!` inverts its value, so if `$SCREEN_NAME` is a non-NULL string containing only the allowed characters, `! [[ $SCREEN_NAME =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$ ]]`'s value is 1.

So the condition is ok.

Run `echo $SCREEN_NAME` in both `bash` and your script and check whether the actual output matches what's expected.

**Edit**: To remove the trailing carriage return, one solution is to pipe `grep`'s output to `tr` before `cut`:

```
SCREEN_NAME=$(grep -i 'server_screen_title' server.properties | tr -d '\r' | cut -f2 -d'=')
```

Comment: Ah!! It was, actually, a `\r` character, so `tr -d '\n\r'` (specify both, just to be safe) worked! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @muru Why / where is it different?

Comment: @muru ? I disagree with this. It doesn't change a bit, other than how it fits the way you're picturing the thing your mind.

Comment: @muru Actually it's even worse, because by striping all possible carriage returns in the source file you need parse the whole file which has a cost of `c*N` where `N` is the number of characters in the source file, while in the other case the cost is always `c*M` but `M` is either equal or less than `N`.

Comment: @muru It's not the same cost to compare and to compare + replace.

Comment: @muru Compare and replace, compare and delete, whatever, always more than just compare.

Comment: @muru I don't feel like I was arguing with you, anyway no, I genuinely feel that doing something ahead of time on a bigger dataset it's just a wrong approach, being `grep` lazier than `tr` and a quick look at `tr` source code seems to suggest this is true. Anyway if you feel like this is just arguing about the thing I'll stop here as well, because I have no interest in arguing as well at all. In fact I tought it was a constructive discussion.